# Create Date from Year, Month and Day Columns in Athena SQL query

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have 3 columns in a table with names year, month and day. I want to return date from this in the format yyyy-mm-dd. What is a good way of doing it?

Comment: What does the data looks like? Please provide a few rows of sample data, along with the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

| year | month | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 05 | 25 |

Functions used:

- [concat](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/concatenating-strings-and-arrays.html)
- [date](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html)

Query to create sample data and then apply the functions in the SELECT statement:

```sql
with sample as (
select
  '2023' year,
  '05' month,
  '25' day
)
select
  date(year||'-'||month||'-'||day) my_date
from sample
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**